# If $y=x^x$, then would it be correct to say $y^{1/x}=\log_x y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I started off with $y=x^x$

Then $y^{(1/x)}=(x^x)^{(1/x)}$

To give $y^{1/x}=x$

Then I decided to take the logarithm of both sides of the original equation:

$$\log_x y = \log_x (x^x)$$

Then $\log_x y = x\log_x (x)$

To give $\log_x y = x$

Is it correct to say that $y^{1/x}=\log_x y$?

Comment: It looks OK as long as x (> 1) and y are positive reals.

Comment: Yes, with herb's restrictions, but also, it only holds if $y = x^x$. You can't just plug in random numbers into the last statement, so, if you plug in $x = 2$, you can't just say $\sqrt{y} = \log_2 (y)$. That will only be true when you also have $y = x^x = 2^2=4$.